# PHP/Apache: Permission settings for linked graphic files

Tags: php, apache, file-permissions

I have some graphics files that exist within a directory that a web server is hosted from. I want to re-use those graphics files for another webservice.

I created a symbolic link as follows:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root    root      51 Jun 30 03:47 gifs -> /var/www/vhosts/webservice/httpdocs/gifs
```

The gifs folder in question has the following permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x  6 user2 psacln    4096 Jun  1 07:02 gifs
```

and a test file in there has this permission

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user1   psacln    1663 Jun 10 09:27 noimage.gif
```

So from the webservice I can view the file fine using http://www.windowsmobilesoft.net/gifs/noimage.gif

but if I use the webserver where the symbolic link is created I get a permission error

http://www.pocketpcsoft.net/gifs/noimage.gif

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access
>   /gifs/noimage.gif on this server.
>
> Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at
>   www.pocketpcsoft.net Port 80

I added apache to the psacln group but this has not made any difference.

I suspect it's something really simple that I need to do, but I cannot think what that is, can anyone help?

Thanks,

Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its more likely that your apache instance is configured not to follow symbolic links than you have a permissions problem.

See [options +symlinks](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#options)

Note that allowing apache to read symlinks may introduce [vulnerabilities in your application](https://serverfault.com/questions/244592/followsymlinks-on-apache-why-is-it-a-security-risk) - better solutions are:

- use hard links (if the vhost doc roots will stay on the same filesystem)
- use rewrite rules to map the image URL to the file
- use alias to map the image URL to the file
- just copy the damn files!

Answer (score 0):

go into the gifs folder on putty, and type: **chmod 0755 noimage.gif**

edit:
go on the folder that contains gifs folder on putty and type:
**chmod 0755 gifs**

then go into the folder and type:
**chmod 0755 noimage.gif**

Comment: did that, it has made no difference

Comment: give the same permission to the folder "gifs" too: chmod 0755 gifs